# PHPUnit Tests Not Being Executed

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following code in PHP and when I run it through phpunit, I get back a message about "No tests executed!"

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


class Calculator

{

    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

}


class CalculatorTest
{
    private $calculator;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->calculator = NULL;
    }

    public function test_Add_1and2_Expect3()
    {
        $result = $this->calculator->add(1, 2);
        $this->assertEquals(3, $result);
    }

}


?>
```

I even tried putting the Calculator class into it's own file and provided the line /require '/home/Documents/PHPTests/calculator/src/Calculator.php'; but still that doesn't work.  I'm using PHPUnit version 8.4.3.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line:

```
class CalculatorTest extends TestCase
```